# Systemd Unit which executes script on unlock GDM?

Tags: systemd

I have some 2 systemd units already running for a similar purpose. There is a unit myservice.service from type simple, which is executed when GDM starts, because of:

```
[Unit]
Description="Download fresh filee"
After=network-online.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=username
RemainAfterExit=true
StandardOutput=journal
ExecStart=/home/user/Documents/myscript.sh
ExecStop=/home/user/Documents/myscript.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

This works fine so far. Then there is a unit myservice.path. This monitors a file. If this file is modified, it executes also myservice.service:

```
[Unit]
Description="Monitor file"
After=network-online.target 
Wants=network-online.target

[Path]
PathModified=/home/user/Documents/myfi.le
Unit=myservice.service

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Additionally, I want to start myservice.service (or the script in ExecStart from this unit) when a user unlock a Gnome/GDM session. I have tried to find a solution, but found nothing really useful. If I'm right, I should use a systemd unit with type=dbus. But type=dbus requires a BusName=

But I have absolute no idea what this means for my usecase. In fact, I will only to start the Script one time on unlock the actual session. If the session is locked again (after timeout or manually) and unlocked again, the script should be executed again.

Comment: `graphical.target` on the `--system` bus will trigger when GDM starts.  When a user logs in via GDM, `graphical-session.target` on the `--user` bus will trigger.  That will invoke your script once per user.  If that suits your needs, I can write up an answer.

Comment: If in this case, it triggers also on unlock after suspend/hibernate, this is exactly what I need. I have tried manually lock via Super + L and unlock the session, in hope to get it triggered, but this was not successful.

Comment: @Angled do you have to use a systemd script to detect this? Because I see there is a command which can monitor when the screen is locked/unlocked. Hopefully the suggestion by Stewart works in this case. I'll  give a try :).